# QML element positioning works unexpectedly

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

This is my custom control. It draws background. I want it to occupy the whole header. But none of methods works, expect setting width and height explicitly, using some numbers. Even *parent.width* and *parent.height* does not work.

Control - TabViewHeaderBg.

Code:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import MyControls 1.0

Item
{
    property int preInfoColumnWidth
    property int nameColumnWidth
    property int progressColumnWidth
    property int sizeColumnWidth
    property int columnSpacing

    height: 40

    TabViewHeaderBg
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Row
    {
        spacing: columnSpacing

        Row
        {
            width: preInfoColumnWidth

            CheckBox
            {

            }
        }

        Text
        {
            text: "Name"
            width: nameColumnWidth
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }

        Text
        {
            text: "Status"
            width: progressColumnWidth
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }

        Text
        {
            text: "Size"
            width: sizeColumnWidth
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }
    }
}
```

This whole control is used as the header control in ListView.

**Addition #1.**

TabViewHeaderBgQc code:

```
class TabViewHeaderBgQc :
        public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TabViewHeaderBgQc(
            QQuickItem *parent = 0);

    void paint(QPainter *painter) override;

signals:

public slots:
};

TabViewHeaderBgQc::TabViewHeaderBgQc(
        QQuickItem *parent) :
    QQuickPaintedItem(parent)
{

}

void TabViewHeaderBgQc::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    QPen pen(QColor(229,229,229), 1);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->drawRect(boundingRect());
}
```

Imports with the following code:

```
qmlRegisterType<TabViewHeaderBgQc>("MyControls", 1, 0, "TabViewHeaderBg");
```

**Addition #2.**

Qt 5.8, Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: show code of TabViewHeaderBg, please

Comment: It's a c++ control derived from QQuickPaintedItem. It does not contain any useful code currently...

Comment: Your code must be reproducible, and without it it is not.

Comment: OK, Please look at Addition #1.

Comment: Added info about qt ver and os, just in case...

Comment: You could explain me better in what you want and show us what you get and what you expect.

Comment: How do you set the width/height of the root `Item`? 

If you expect that root `Item` will derive its dimensions from its children, that won't work. You could set the root `Item`'s `implicitWidth` and `implicitHeight` to the outer `Row`'s `implicitWidth` and `implicitHeight`. In this case this `Row` item will specify the dimensions of this component. 

You could also set the `implicitWidth` and `implicitHeight` of the root `Item` in the `ListView` when you create this object to the `ListView`'s `contentWidth` and `contentHeight`

Comment: Yes, setting width of root Item to parent.width helped. Thank you! Please post it as an answer. I'll mark it.